# Access to SQS Queue is denied even when policies are set

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-sqs

We have a reader that reads messages from an SQS Queue. Locally it works, however when we deploy to ECS, we recieve an exception:

> Access to the resource [queue-url] is denied.

We can access the queue locally, i.e. when we initialize the client with a Profile through CredentialProfileStoreChain. We have also double and triple checked all policies and permissions - all the resources have the needed access to one another (i.e. ECS -> read/write/delete SQS).

I believe I'm not initializing the AmazonSQSClient properly, but I have followed all documentation, and tried various options.

Code below:

My **SqsClientFactory** (which an AmazonSQSClient):

```
public static AmazonSQSClient CreateClient(AppSettings appSettings)
{
    var sqsConfig = new AmazonSQSConfig()
    {
        RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(appSettings.Region)
    };          

    //For testing on the local machine - this works
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(appSettings.AwsProfile))
    {

        var credentialProfileStoreChain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();
        AWSCredentials credentials;
        credentialProfileStoreChain.TryGetAWSCredentials(appSettings.Aws.Profile, out credentials);

        return new AmazonSQSClient(credentials, sqsConfig);
    }           
    
    //For deployed versions
    return new AmazonSQSClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(appSettings.Region));
    //Also tried:
    //return new AmazonSQSClient(sqsConfig));
    //return new AmazonSQSClient();

}
```

Am I missing something regarding initializing an AmazongSQSClient properly?

Comment: Is the SQS in another Account as the ECS container?

Comment: Yes, same account

Comment: Can you share more of your code? Where do you set the queue URL?

Comment: Ìt ended up working with just return new AmazonSQSClient(). We played around with the policies and configuration, but I have no idea why it works now and didn't work earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, and of course it was somewthing astoundingly stupid. Someone had checked in a appsettings.json file with the profile value not being empty, ie "profile: #aws_profile#". It was left over from when these settings were to be injected during the pipeline execution, before we opted for the Parameter store.

That means that this part:

> if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(appSettings.AwsProfile))

was true, and never reached the proper code.

Comment: Okay interesting, thanks to sharing. Don't use .json files for env data. Makes things complicated and you can push confidential data In git.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that both the following policies allow access to the SQS queue

- Resource (SQS) based policy:
  The SQS queue should allow your identity to use the queue. You define this using the queue policy (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-iam.html#scenario-sqs-policy). The default queue policy will allow access only to the owner of the queue (owner of the queue is the identity that created the queue).

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-task.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": arn:aws:sqs:<region>:<account>:<queue name>",
    }
  ]
}
```

- Identity based policies: The policy for the identity that is accessing the queue should have permission to invoke operations on the queue. In this case the TaskRole

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sqs:DeleteMessage",
                "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
                "sqs:SendMessage"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:<region>:<account>:<queue name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

Make sure that the access is not restricted by either one of them.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-using-identity-based-policies.html

Comment: Yes all of these have been set up, we've checked and double checked many times. I'm at a loss

Comment: Try out a basic example to check your code https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/SendMessage.html

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: If permissions are fine it might be that your code is something wrong

Comment: The service is `ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com` not `ecs-task.amazonaws.com`